# Ionic get Drag Coordinates

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm new to working with Ionic and would like to get the current coordinates of the touch(or mouse) while pressed(update every 100ms or smth).
So the coordinates where the mouse is while pressed.
I've tried it with the Ionic Pan gesture but couldn't get it to work.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Did this answer your question? Please let us now if you need anything else :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple ion-content element and capture the click event in your comp

```
<ion-content (click)="getCoordinates($event)">
 This is my main content
</ion-content>
```

Then in your component code just use event.clientX like this:

```
getCoordinates(ev) { 
  console.log('x: ' + ev.clientX + ' y: ' + ev.clientY);
}
```